# Empty fields on a form will consider a pre existing value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website where the user can create a profile. However, if he decides to make any alteration on that profile, he can go to `alterar_cadastro.php` and make that changes he desire. Code of the file bellow:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('verifica_login.php');

$email = $_SESSION['usuario'];

$busca_nivel = "SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE email = '$email' OR sobrenome = '$email'";
$resultado_busca_nivel = mysqli_query($conexao, $busca_nivel);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_busca_nivel);

?>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1"></div>
            <div class="col-10">
                <br>
                <h3>Preencha os dados abaixo para alterar seu cadastro:</h3>
                <br>
                    <form method="post" action="processa_alteracao.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nome">Nome: </label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="<?php echo $rows['nome'] ?>"><br>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-group">Apelido: </label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sobrenome" placeholder="<?php echo $rows['sobrenome'] ?>">
                            <small class="form-text text-muted">Atenção! Mudar seu apelido significa mudar o seu login.</small>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nome">Cidade: </label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cidade" placeholder="<?php echo $rows['cidade'] ?>"><br>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-group">Estado: </label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="estado" placeholder="<?php echo $rows['estado'] ?>">
                            <small class="form-text text-muted">Escreva o seu estado de forma abreviada. Ex.: AM, AC, DF, TO.</small>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-group">Quem é você? </label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="geral" placeholder="<?php echo $rows['geral'] ?>"></textarea>
                            <small class="form-text text-muted">Nos fale um pouquinho sobre quem é você e o que espera da nossa plataforma :) Máximo de caracteres: 100.</small>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-group">E-mail: </label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="<?php echo $rows['email']; ?>" readonly>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-group">Foto para o perfil: </label><input type="file" name="foto_perfil">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-group">Senha: </label><input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Insira sua senha para confirmar"><br><br>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Alterar Perfil</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, if the user leaves one of the inputs blank, that's the value going to MYSQL. I put bellow the php file that process this information:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';

$email = $_SESSION['usuario'];

$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['nome']);
$sobrenome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['sobrenome']);
$cidade = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['cidade']);
$estado = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['estado']);
$geral = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['geral']);
$perfil = $_FILES['foto_perfil'];
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);

$query_cad = "SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha' OR sobrenome = '$sobrenome' AND senha = '$senha'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query_cad);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$fk_cad = $row2['entry_cod_cad'];

if($row == 1) {

    if(isset($perfil)){

    $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['foto_perfil']['name'], -4));
    $novo_nome = md5(time()) . $extensao;
    $diretorio = "img/perfil/";

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto_perfil']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);    
    }

    $query = "UPDATE cadastro SET nome = '$nome', sobrenome = '$sobrenome', cidade = '$cidade', estado = '$estado', geral = '$geral', perfil = '$novo_nome' WHERE entry_cod_cad = '$fk_cad'";
    $result_alteracao = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

    $msg = "success";
    echo "<script>alert('$msg');window.location.assign('/index.php?pagina=perfil');</script>";

} else {

    $msg = "incorrect";
    echo "<script>alert('$msg');window.location.assign('/index.php?pagina=inicio');</script>";
}
```

My question is: How do I make the empty fields have a pre existing value, where this value is the one that already is in his profile. I thought that the `value` attribute inside `<input>` would do the trick, however, I was not successful.

Comment: You are using the `placeholder`, not the `value`. The `value` will indeed do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use value parameter instead of placeholder

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('verifica_login.php');

    $email = $_SESSION['usuario'];

    $busca_nivel = "SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE email = '$email' OR sobrenome = '$email'";
    $resultado_busca_nivel = mysqli_query($conexao, $busca_nivel);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_busca_nivel);

    ?>

    <html>
        <head>

        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1"></div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <br>
                    <h3>Preencha os dados abaixo para alterar seu cadastro:</h3>
                    <br>
                        <form method="post" action="processa_alteracao.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nome">Nome: </label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $rows['nome'] ?>"><br>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-group">Apelido: </label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sobrenome" value="<?php echo $rows['sobrenome'] ?>">
                                <small class="form-text text-muted">Atenção! Mudar seu apelido significa mudar o seu login.</small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nome">Cidade: </label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cidade" value="<?php echo $rows['cidade'] ?>"><br>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-group">Estado: </label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="estado" value="<?php echo $rows['estado'] ?>">
                                <small class="form-text text-muted">Escreva o seu estado de forma abreviada. Ex.: AM, AC, DF, TO.</small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-group">Quem é você? </label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="geral" value="<?php echo $rows['geral'] ?>"></textarea>
                                <small class="form-text text-muted">Nos fale um pouquinho sobre quem é você e o que espera da nossa plataforma :) Máximo de caracteres: 100.</small>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-group">E-mail: </label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $rows['email']; ?>" readonly>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-group">Foto para o perfil: </label><input type="file" name="foto_perfil">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-group">Senha: </label><input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Insira sua senha para confirmar"><br><br>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Alterar Perfil</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```